# How to read multiple sets of value in the excel sheet using DataProvider in Selenium WebDriver with Java and TestNG

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm fairly new to Selenium WebDriver. I wrote code to read the login credentials and values from the excel sheet by using Data Provider.
It runs through the first set up data(login functionality) perfectly giving me the green status bar.

In my application, after login, I want to select values by sending index and Selection(In Administration Method) from the same excel sheet but I failed to read values. 
For hard coded values its working fine.

can anyone please give me the idea how to write it.
Used Excel Sheet:

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.File;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class TestCase {

String[][] tabArray = null;
Workbook workbk;
Sheet sheet;
int rowCount, colCount;
String sheetPath = "test/Resources/Data/Auto_Increment.xls";
WebDriver login;
//int eRow, eCol, sRow = 0, sCol = 0;


@BeforeSuite
public void setUp(){
    login = new FirefoxDriver();
    login.get("http://etazo.tangosoftware.com");
    System.out.println("select the etazo web link..");
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getLoginData() throws Exception {
    Object[][] retObjArr = getExcelData(sheetPath, "Sheet1");
    System.out.println("getData function executed!!");
    return retObjArr;
}

//  Excel API to read test data from excel workbook
public String[][] getExcelData(String xlPath, String shtName)
        throws Exception {
    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlPath));
    Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet(shtName);
    rowCount = sht.getRows();
    colCount = sht.getColumns();
    tabArray = new String[rowCount][colCount - 2];
    System.out.println("erow: " + rowCount);
    System.out.println("ecol: " + colCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            tabArray[i][j] = sht.getCell(j, i).getContents();
        }
    }
    return (tabArray);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "getLoginData")
public void LoginData(String distID, String asmtId, String studID)
        throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {
    Administartion(distID, asmtId, studID);
}
public void Administartion(String distID, String asmtId, String studID)
        throws BiffException, IOException {
    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(sheetPath));
    Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int currRow = sht.findCell(studID).getRow();
    //login.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='question-"+sIndex+"']/bubbles/circle["+sValue+"]")).click();     
    System.out.println(sht.getCell(3, currRow).getContents() + " Index ");
    System.out.println(sht.getCell(4, currRow).getContents() + " Answer selection");
}
```

}

Comment: Try passing the "distID, "asmtId, "studID" to the "Administration()" function as parameters..

Comment: Hi Praveen, I have parameterized "distId", "asmtID", "StudID" in the Administration function. Its taking the values but after login its not selecting any values. I have removed the LoginData method but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, You are correct. when you are calling the "Adminstration()", pass the same parameters to it like "Administration(distId, asmtId, studId)". This will make the variables available even inside the "administration()".

Comment: I have done exactly same only. but my worry is after login I have to select some values but i'm unable to select those values. Its working fine for login functionality.  Bz in the getExcelMethod() its sending only login parameters. Im not getting where exactly I have to parameter index and values. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sure, I will have to replicate it to understand/comment on it. Can you share/show how your excel sheet looks like.

Comment: I tried to attach my excel sheet but i'm getting reputation error message. How to resolve the error message?

Comment: may be you can send it to me over mail (praveen.kumar1254(At)GmailDotCom

Comment: I have sent my excel sheet to your mail id. Please check it.

Comment: Its pretty simple. Since the cells from A2 - A10 and B2 - B10 are empty, there will be some null pointer error. Try to fill the data in these cells with A1 value and B1 value. Give a try and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried and I got null pointer exception. Just now updated latest code here(In the Administration method). Please check it.

Comment: I have tried the same code u have shared here.
But it didn't work for me. I have shared same code here.

Answer (score 0):

edited the code. Now this will fetch all the records.

And your excel sheet should look something similar to this: 
[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {
    String[][] tabArray = null;
    Workbook workbk;
    Sheet sheet;
    int rowCount, colCount;
    String sheetPath = "D:\\Download\\Auto_Increment.xls";

    // Excel API to read test data from excel workbook
    public String[][] getExcelData(String xlPath, String shtName)
            throws Exception {
        Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlPath));
        Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet(shtName);
        rowCount = sht.getRows();
        colCount = sht.getColumns();
        tabArray = new String[rowCount][colCount - 2];
        System.out.println("erow: " + rowCount);
        System.out.println("ecol: " + colCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                tabArray[i][j] = sht.getCell(j, i).getContents();
            }
        }
        return (tabArray);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getLoginData() throws Exception {
        Object[][] retObjArr = getExcelData(sheetPath, "Sheet1");
        System.out.println("getData function executed!!");
        return retObjArr;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getLoginData")
    public void LoginData(String distID, String asmtId, String studID)
            throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {
        Administartion(distID, asmtId, studID);
    }

    public void Administartion(String distID, String asmtId, String studID)
            throws BiffException, IOException {
        Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(sheetPath));
        Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int currRow = sht.findCell(studID).getRow();
        System.out.println(sht.getCell(3, currRow).getContents() + " Index ");
        System.out.println(sht.getCell(4, currRow).getContents() + " Answer selection");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Code goes here to read xlsx file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestDataProvider {
    static File resultFile = new File(“PATH OF THE EXCEL”);
    public static DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

    @Test(dataProvider = "readExcelFile")
    public static void test1(String slNum, String name, String Address, String email) throws  IOException {
        System.out.println(slNum+" "+ name+" "+Address + " "+email);

    FURTHER CODE GOES HERE


    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] readExcelFile() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet(“SHEET NAME”);

        System.out.println(sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
        System.out.println(sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
        int RowNum = sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int ColNum = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

        String[][] xlData = new String[RowNum-1][ColNum];

        for (int i = 0; i < RowNum - 1; i++) 
        {
            XSSFRow row = sh.getRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < ColNum; j++) 
            {
                if (row == null)
                    xlData[i][j] = "";
                else {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);                 
                    if (cell == null)
                        xlData[i][j] = ""; 
                    else {
                        String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        xlData[i][j] = value.trim();                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return xlData;
    }   
}
```